# How do I make an ellipse rotate on its axis with svg?

Tags: html, animation, svg

I'm learning about how to animate with svg in HTML, and I need to rotate an ellips on its axis, so how I do it?

The only thing that I could do was to rotate the ellipse around the point x="0" y="0".

```
  <ellipse cx="500" cy="300" rx="80" ry="160" transform="rotate(<angle> 0 0)">
        <animateTransform 
          attributeName="transform"
          from="0"
          to="360"
          dur="10s"
          repeatCount="1"/>
```

Comment: The "0 0" in your `rotate()` transform are the X and Y of the centre of rotation.  Change those values to the point you want to rotate around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
   <ellipse cx="240" cy="240" rx="80" ry="160">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 240 240"
                          to="360 240 240"
                          dur="10s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

Basically the SMIL animation should point at the shape's center. In case of my Ellipse here it is 240,240 (cx, cy)